# How to parse django style template tags

Tags: php, regex, django-templates

What's the best way to parse django style template tags in PHP? I know there are plenty of templating libraries for PHP, but I literally just need to parse one tag when I retrieve data from my database.

The style of tag I want to parse looks like `{{ form | form_name }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEX is the way to go.

```
\{\{ *form *\| *(\S+) *\}\}
```

should do the trick nicely.

---

A bit of explaining:

- `\{` and `\}` will each match `{` and `}` respectively.
- `*` will match for 0 to infinite space characters ().
- `(\S+)` will match for 1 to infinite non-space characters (`a, B, 3, _ etc`).