# How to read .php file and display tagged areas within php file

Tags: php, variables, directory, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse django style template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650833/how-to-parse-django-style-template-tags)

I need some help with making a code that can read any number of .php files in a given directory, look for "tagged" areas on those pages, such as:

```
<? ####
# ((((((Test Area)))))
#### ?>

(some html)

<? ####
# ((((((Test Area2)))))
#### ?>
```

and display those "tagged" areas.  I currently have code that reads .php files in a given directory and pulls text out of there between `{{{{{ }}}}}` (for example `{{{{{Content}}}}}` in the head of the page and displays it in a drop down menu.  So what I am trying to do is when I select for instance Content from the drop down menu, the code would look in that directory, look for Content.php, and scan the file looking for the "tagged" areas, and then echo them.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So you're using the templating system known as PHP to roll your own meta-templating system? Yo dawg...

Comment: @MarcB I herd you liek templating systems so I made a templating system in ur templating system

Answer (score 0):

I'd research the Smarty Template system.

Essentially you're doing regex searches in long strings. So, first get the string:

```
$template = file_get_contents('myfile.tpl.php');
```

Then do a search using the regex method of your choice. Probably using the following php method like this:

```
$search = "/^\{\{\{\{\{somePlaceholder\}\}\}\}\}/";
$replace = $yourNode;    
$scrubbedTemplate = preg_replace($search, $replace, $template);
print $scrubbedTemplate;
```

NOTE: My intuition is telling me that you're approaching this the wrong way. The way MVC frameworks include templates is probably better. They'd actually do an include_once('file.tpl.php') and they'd have real php variables in that file that just have values before the include is called.

Comment: Would it be easier to have a script that scanned the directory of .php files, looked at each file, grabbed the unique name inside the tag identifier areas, and inserted them into the mysql table?